# Retrieve minimum and maximum strings from database table

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle

I have one database table data like following.

```
abc
bcd
cdef
ferd
testd
```

I need to get minimum and maximum values like following

```
abc
testd
```

How can I write SQL query to get above output?

Comment: Is this Oracle or MySQL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you want to retrieve the min and max values in *two separate rows*:

```
SELECT your_column FROM your_table
    JOIN
    (SELECT
        min(your_column) AS min_v,
        max(your_column) AS max_v FROM your_table
    ) minmax
    WHERE your_column IN(minmax.min_v,minmax.max_v);
```

Comment: @mathguy join_condition is optional on Inner joins under mysql. See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/join.html

Comment: @mathguy An unqualifed JOIN under mysql is interpreted as INNER JOIN (so the JOIN under the answer query is qualified by default to  INNER). Furthermore, regarding your concerns about INNER JOINS, if you follow the doc I've provided you can read `In MySQL, JOIN, CROSS JOIN, and INNER JOIN are syntactic equivalents (they can replace each other). In standard SQL, they are not equivalent. INNER JOIN is used with an ON clause, CROSS JOIN is used otherwise.`.

Comment: Yes, I got that (replied before I read, sorry - that's why I deleted it). CROSS JOIN is what I was suggesting with "can be saved". In Oracle the Where... IN (...) won't work either, it will have to be written differently.

Answer (score 1):

If you need two row you ca use union

```
select min(my_column) 
from my_table 
union 
select max(my_column) 
from my_table
```

or union all for avoiding  that return only distinct value

```
select min(my_column) 
from my_table 
union all
select max(my_column) 
from my_table
```

if you need on one row you can

```
select min(my_column), max(my_column) from my_table;
```

Comment: This is better than the accepted answer because it doesn't need the extra join. But it should use *union all* instead of only *union*, because union returns only distinct values

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT min(field) as minValue, max(field) as maxValue FROM yourTable
```

This assumes that the min/max is based on DB defaults, and nothing more complex.